# user select background issues

Tags: php

**OVERVIEW**: I have script which allows users to chose a background and this option is saved in the mysqlDB. This is then pulled at login and saved within the session.

**Issue:** The problem I am having is that in I.E. only the background shows and the web content does not. It works in chrome, and I have read up on different ways to show the background, but it seems to not be working. Is there anything wrong with my script?

**Script**:

```
<style> body { background: url('http://domain.co.uk/images/assets/<?php echo "".$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"]."" ?>.jpg')  no-repeat top; } </style>
```

*session start script*

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["USER"])){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

*check login / gen session*

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
while($user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"] = $user_data["bg"];
```

My start session script and generate works, and I have posted the relevent snippits here

Comment: if u don't mind can we see ur script

Comment: @Rsmithy Actually it would be cool if you provide a link to your site (if it's live).

Comment: http://ts.robsmithy.co.uk is the site.
Username/Password = sos

Comment: try to debug output from `<?php echo "".$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"]."" ?>` and why not just write  `<?=$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"];?>` instead?

Comment: @loler I have `<style> body { background: url('http://robsmithy.co.uk/ts/win8/assets/<?=$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"]?>.jpg')  no-repeat top; } </style>` ...Cheers, gave it a try ...it works on chrome, but the content still doesn't show on I.E.

Comment: I have IE9, and I've tested this with IE 8/9/10 and it has the same fault

Comment: Are you sure it works in IE without this line?

Comment: Yes, I have removed the line if you would want to visit the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `<style>` must be included inside `head`. Or you can just add attribute `style="background: url('http://example.com/images/assets/<?=$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"]?>.jpg"` to `<body>` tag. I think that will help.

Comment: well, that's seem'd to of done the trick.. yesterday, it did work, but stopped. Now it works, and this a new thing I've tried. Seems logical. It was outside the `<html>` at the top after the script to ensure you're logged in... cheers